# MediaPlayer Error -38, 0 in Service android

Tags: java, android, service

I have service with MediaPlayer inside and Activity with play/pause button. When I click on button, I call startService, but instead of playing music I catch error:

```
09-01 19:10:10.216  15652-15652/com.itis.playerbuttontest E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 4
09-01 19:10:10.216  15652-15652/com.itis.playerbuttontest E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
09-01 19:10:10.230  15652-15652/com.itis.playerbuttontest E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
```

There is my Service code

```
public class AudioService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

public static final String URL = "https://cs1-43v4.vk-cdn.net/p7/ad8c4f11cc535b.mp3?extra=CHu-724p52zJOrv5ebIhtHeN1rtSvD21LMlBmqODVgmB1zag_CkzocrdSxWpkweYMG_9cRgM_7z_izqbLsXzIX7KJ8EfuD-d";

private void releaseMp() {
    if (mPlayer != null) {
        mPlayer.release();
    }
    mPlayer = null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    try {
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mPlayer.setDataSource(URL);
        mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mPlayer.prepareAsync();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    releaseMp();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals("PLAY") && !mPlayer.isPlaying()) {

        mPlayer.start();
    } else {
        mPlayer.pause();
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.start();
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    stopSelf();
    }
}
```

And there is Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

boolean playing = false;
private MorphButton button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (MorphButton) findViewById(R.id.playPauseBtn);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AudioService.class);
            i.setAction(playing ? "PAUSE" : "PLAY");
            playing = !playing;
            startService(i);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    stopService(new Intent(this, AudioService.class));
    }
}
```

So, what's wrong there?

Comment: I've solved this problem. There was incorrect URL. But now I have another problem. When I launch app on Android 4+, everything ok, but when I try click on button on Android 2.3, mediaplayer doesn't start. I've watched logcat and seen that onPrepare method doesn't call? Also I catch Why?

Comment: Also I catch error (1, -2147483648).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error is because when the service starts, the media player isn't yet prepared. 
So when you call `mPlayer.start()` the exception is thrown.

In Service `onCreate()`, instead of `mPlayer.prepareAsync()` try `mPlayer.prepare()`.